# How to do multiple-file output of Hive with Python?

Tags: python, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

Given a query

```
select category, value from someHiveTable;
```

I expect to output the result above of each category into one separate file named by the corresponding category.

EDIT:

```
hive -e "select category, value from someHiveTable" >./output.csv
```

can output to only one file.

Any tips how to output the result to multiple files for each category?

Comment: Show us what you've tried and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: If you have python code to show, add the python tag back in

Comment: @cricket_007 There should be no solution to make multiple file output directly within Hive. We need python, man.

Comment: Are you trying to run the hive query from python? If so, show that code. Are you trying to read the output of the CSV in python? Show that code.

Comment: @cricket_007 As the title of OP mentioned, I tried to run python in Hive. If I already has the solution, I would love to share it.

Comment: You can't run Python from Hive, only Hive from Python. I suggest you research how to run a shell command in Python.

Comment: @cricket_007 We do can run Python in Hive. Hive is simply a wrapper for mapreduce process. We can run Python, Perl, Bash, and any command in Hive!

Comment: @cricket_007 Please refer to the answer from amit_kumar to learn how to use python in Hive. Please cancel your thumb down. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote, so I have nothing to cancel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it will help but surely if you don't find anything else you can try..

```
select TRANSFORM(category, value) USING 'yourCustomScript' from someHiveTable
```

this will give single line tab separated inputs to your custom script , there you can try righting outputs to different files according to your inputs. You can do little more research on TRANSFORM and USING.